# left, midle, and right dragging with the mouse (jquery events)

Tags: jquery, events, mouse, drag

I am very new to Javascript and need help for something. I display an image in a canvas, and I would like to get different events when dragging on this image : for example, zoom when dragging with the midle button of the mouse, translation when dragging on the image with the right button of the mouse... I was able to catch these events when using Chrome, but my code does not work when I try it with Firefox. Could you give me some help please ? Here is my code :

```
isDragging = false;
// Mousedown : isDragging is true and get mouse position
$("#s1").bind('mousedown', function(event)
{
    isDragging = true;
});
// Mouseup : isDragging is false
$("#s1").bind('mouseup', function(event)
{
    isDragging = false;
});
// Mousemove : handle window level, translation, zoom, slice changing
$("#s1").bind('mousemove', function(event)
{
    if (isDragging) 
    {
        switch (event.which) 
        {
            case 1 : // left : window level
                alert('left dragging');
                break;
            case 2 : // mousewheel : zoom
                alert('mousewheel dragging');
                break;
            case 3 : 
                alert('right dragging');
                break;
            default :
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I played with it and figured it out. It seems that Firefox does not send a proper event.which on mousemove. It is actually kind of weird that it works in Chrome since logically the mouse position should not really be related to what button is currently down. 
You want to check event.which on the mouseup and mousedown listeners. This also lets you drag with more than one button at once (If that is useful).

Also I prefer to use console.log() to alert() for debugging because alert stops everything. Hit F12 in any browser to see the javascript console.

I hope that helps! :D

```
leftIsDragging   = false;
middleIsDragging = false;
rightIsDragging  = false;  

$(document).bind('mousedown', function(event) {

    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            console.log('Left mouse down.');
            leftIsDragging   = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Middle mouse down.');
            middleIsDragging = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('Right mouse down.');
            rightIsDragging   = true;
            break;
        default:
             console.log('Other mouse down.');
    }
});

$(document).bind('mouseup', function(event) {

    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            console.log('Left mouse up.');
            leftIsDragging   = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Middle mouse up.');
            middleIsDragging = false;
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('Right mouse up.');
            rightIsDragging  = false;
            break;
        default:
             console.log('Other mouse up.');
    }
});

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (leftIsDragging) 
    {
        console.log('left dragging');
    }
    if (middleIsDragging) 
    {
        console.log('mousewheel dragging');
    }
    if (rightIsDragging) 
    {
        console.log('right dragging');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and advice, this was exactly the problem, and I still don't understand why it was working using Chrome !